# Двойная буферизация C++ WINAPI при отрисовке изображения

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Появилась необходимость заняться WINAPI, почитал на MSDN, что-то понял, что-то нет. Когда картинка не двигается, то все хорошо, но мне необходимо чтобы она двигалась в процессе выполнения, двигаться я ее заставил, но при этом она периодически моргает. Посмотрел в том же MSDN как сделать двойную буферизацию, скопировал код, и ничего, как моргала, так и моргает, ну быть может плавнее двигаться стало. Прошу помочь, с WINAPI не работал вообще.

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "lab1.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "msimg32")
using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HDC hdc;
HBITMAP hbitmap = NULL;
HBITMAP hBackBuffer = NULL;
long image_width = 354, image_height = 430, window_w, window_h;
RECT rect;
int delta_w = 0, delta_h = 0, olddelta_w = 0, olddelta_h = 0;
HBITMAP hBkBitmap = nullptr, hTransparentBitmap = nullptr;
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_LAB1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    hBkBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LAB1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LAB1));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LAB1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_LAB1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
static HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(hInst, L"1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
void Paint(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc)
{
    HDC hdcMem;
    HBITMAP hbmMem, hbmOld;
    HBRUSH hbrBkGnd;
    HFONT hfntOld;
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, window_w, window_h);
    hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);
    hbrBkGnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    FillRect(hdcMem, &rect, hbrBkGnd);
    DeleteObject(hbrBkGnd);
    SetBkMode(hdcMem, TRANSPARENT);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, delta_w, delta_h, image_width, image_height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    window_h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    window_w = rect.right - rect.left;
    static int _size;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(hInst, L"1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Paint(hWnd, hdc);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if (wParam == 37) 
            {
                delta_w -= 5;
            }
            if (wParam == 39)
            {
                delta_w += 5;
            }
            if (wParam == 38)
            {
                delta_h -= 5;
            }
            if (wParam == 40)
            {
                delta_h += 5;
            }
            delta_h = clamp((long)delta_h, (long)0, window_h - image_height);
            delta_w = clamp((long)delta_w, (long)0, window_w - image_width);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, true);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Двигаю картинку путем изменения delta_w и delta_h при нажатии клавиш

Comment: Код создания окна нужен. А вообще посмотрите в сторону [Direct 2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal)

Comment: Просто создал классическое приложение Windows

Comment: Нужен КОД. Не просто создал, а код, чтобы глянуть как вы там включили буферизацию двойную.

Comment: Добавил, в начале есть объявления переменных, которые не все используются (остались от других попыток реализации)

Comment: Видимо не хватает обработки сообщения `WM_ERASEBKGND`. Поэтому когда сначала стирается весь фон, а затем поверх него рисуется изображение, получается моргание.

Comment: Хорошо, если просто кидать true для него, то при перемещении остается прошлое изображение, и новое частично наслаивается на старое, тогда нужно убрать его, но как сделать это, чтобы не моргало не знаю, уже столько примером посмотрел и ничего

Comment: Надо в обработчике `WM_PAINT` рисовать в битмап и весь фон тоже.

Comment: А можно пример кода, а то я не понимаю, или напрямую что надо у меня поменять, чтобы все заработало как надо